# Showing unread notification count through web manifest

Tags: html, notifications, web-manifest

I recently added a web manifest to my webapp following [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/simplified-app-installs/?hl=en) guide. It works perfectly fine. I have also implemented push notifications. I want to know if there is a way to add an unread notification count like any other android app does indicating number of unread notifications on the launcher icon on the homescreen.

Comment: What's a `web-manifest`?

Comment: Here is a link you can go through http://html5doctor.com/web-manifest-specification/

Comment: I don't think you can yet. But I like where you are thinking!

Answer (score 0):

The WICG Badging API will most likely solve this, but it will take some time before browser implement it.

See https://github.com/WICG/badging/blob/master/explainer.md